# Selecting first child from all elements and nested elements

Tags: css, css-selectors

I need to only select the `first` and `third`/last elements.

It was working fine until I decided to make them links. In my actual source the `divs` are `img`s

```css
body {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}

.this:first-child {
  color: red;
}

.this:last-child {
  color: aqua;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <a href="">
    <div class="this">
      FIRST
    </div>
  </a>
  <a href="">
    <div class="this">
      SECOND
    </div>
  </a>
  <a href="">
    <div class="this">
      THIRD
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `.this` elements are wrapped with another element (`a`), and they are the only children. This means that they are both first and last child, so the last rule takes over. Move the `:first-child` and `:last-child` pseudo-selectors to the `a` elements:

```css
body {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}

a:first-child .this {
  color: red;
}

a:last-child .this {
  color: aqua;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <a href="">
    <div class="this">
      FIRST
    </div>
  </a>
  <a href="">
    <div class="this">
      SECOND
    </div>
  </a>
  <a href="">
    <div class="this">
      THIRD
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
```